# Quick Sort algorithm behaving strangely

Tags: c, sorting, quicksort

This is a program which attempts to sort an array using the quick sort algorithm.
All seems to be fine, except that the output is not correct.

(Try the program for n=5, and then n=10. It works correctly for the former, but not the latter.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
//#include <iostream.h>
//#include <conio.h>

int partition(int arr[], int left, int right)   {
    int i = left, j = right;
    int temp;

    //Choosing the middle element as the pivot
    //int pivot=arr[left];
    int pivot = arr[(left+right)/2];

    while (i <= j) {
        while (arr[i] < pivot) {i++;}
        while (arr[j] > pivot) {j--;}

        if (i <= j) {
            temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = temp;
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }

    return i;
}

void quick_sort(int arr[], int p, int r)   {
    if (p<r)   {
       int q=partition(arr, p, r);
       quick_sort(arr, p, q-1);
       quick_sort(arr, q+1, r);
    }
}

int main()  {
    int values[100], n, i;

    //clrscr();

    printf("Enter no. of elements ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    if (n>100) {
        printf("Invalid input. Exiting now");
        //getch();
        return 0;
    }

    for (i=0; i<100; i++) values[i]=0;

    printf("Enter the numbers\n");
    for (i=0; i<n; i++) scanf("%d", &values[i]);

    printf("The numbers you entered are\n");
    for (i=0; i<n; i++) printf("%d ", values[i]);

    printf("\n");

    quick_sort(values, 0, n-1);

    printf("Numbers after sorting are\n");
    printf("(The output might not be the expected one (Be careful).\n");
    for (i=0; i<n; i++) printf("%d ", values[i]);

    //std::cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you need include an additional swap between `i` and `pivot` at the end of `partition`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive.  You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, by tracing the progress of your program, and comparing it to what you expect to happen.  As soon as the two diverge, then you've found your problem.   (And then if necessary, you should construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).)

Comment: Your pointers can wander out of the range, nothing stops them.

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems. First, the comparison `i <= j` is wrong. If `i == j`, you should not swap an element with itself. This should be changed to `i < j` in both places. Secondly, you should not move the `i` and `j` array indicies along after swapping. If it is the last swap, this pushes `i` past the actual pivot and causes your error.

```
int partition(int arr[], int left, int right)   {
    int i = left, j = right;
    int temp;

    //Choosing the middle element as the pivot
    //int pivot=arr[left];
    int pivot = arr[(left+right)/2];

    while (i < j) {
        while (arr[i] < pivot) {i++;}
        while (arr[j] > pivot) {j--;}

        if (i < j) {
            temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = temp;
        }
    }

    return i;
}
```

Comment: The indices i and j might wander out of the array.

Comment: How? `pivot` is guaranteed to be a value in the array, so `i` will increase until it hits the pivot.

Answer (score -1):

is better to use the std sort from  **algorithm.h** :

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/

Comment: This question is tagged `C`, not `C++`, and the correct include file for `std::sort` is `algorithm`, not `algorithm.h`.